# identityserver3 openid configuration not showing all scopes

Tags: c#, identityserver3

I was reading the [getting started guide of identityserver3](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) and it mentions the open id configuration endpoint:

> identity/.well-known/openid-configuration

which will list your scopes.
In their example it lists:

- openid
- profile
- email
- phone
- address

In my application I created a scope called **api** and when I created my **client** I set **AllowAccessToAllScopes** to true, but when go to the openid configuration endpoint I get this:

```
{  
   "issuer":"https://localhost:44313",
   "jwks_uri":"https://localhost:44313/identity/.well-known/jwks",
   "authorization_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/authorize",
   "token_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/token",
   "userinfo_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/userinfo",
   "end_session_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/endsession",
   "check_session_iframe":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/checksession",
   "revocation_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/revocation",
   "introspection_endpoint":"https://localhost:44313/identity/connect/introspect",
   "frontchannel_logout_supported":true,
   "frontchannel_logout_session_supported":true,
   "scopes_supported":[  
      "api"
   ],
   "claims_supported":[  

   ],
   "response_types_supported":[  
      "code",
      "token",
      "id_token",
      "id_token token",
      "code id_token",
      "code token",
      "code id_token token"
   ],
   "response_modes_supported":[  
      "form_post",
      "query",
      "fragment"
   ],
   "grant_types_supported":[  
      "authorization_code",
      "client_credentials",
      "password",
      "refresh_token",
      "implicit"
   ],
   "subject_types_supported":[  
      "public"
   ],
   "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":[  
      "RS256"
   ],
   "code_challenge_methods_supported":[  
      "plain",
      "S256"
   ],
   "token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":[  
      "client_secret_post",
      "client_secret_basic"
   ]
}
```

As you can see, there is just one scope supported. 
Does anyone know why? Or how I can get all scopes there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. If you look at the link I provided, the first in memory example uses **StandardScopes.All**. I had a look at that in the repository and saw the list of scopes it adds. I decided the change my **ScopeStore** and add these scopes, like this:

```
public class ScopeStore: IScopeStore
{
    private readonly DbContext _context;

    public ScopeStore(DbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Scope>> FindScopesAsync(IEnumerable<string> scopeNames)
    {
        var models = await List().Where(m => scopeNames.Contains(m.Name)).ToListAsync();
        return AddStandardScopes(models);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Scope>> GetScopesAsync(bool publicOnly = true)
    {
        var models = await List(publicOnly).ToListAsync();
        return AddStandardScopes(models);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of Scopes
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="publicOnly">A boolean to show public scopes or not</param>
    /// <returns>The matched Scopes</returns>
    public IQueryable<IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.Scope> List(bool publicOnly = true, params string[] includes)
    {
        var models = _context.Set<IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.Scope>();

        if (publicOnly)
            return models.Where(m => m.ShowInDiscoveryDocument);

        return models;
    }

    private IEnumerable<IdentityServer3.Core.Models.Scope> AddStandardScopes(IEnumerable<IdentityServer3.EntityFramework.Entities.Scope> scopes)
    {
        var models = scopes.Select(m => m.ToModel()).ToList();
        models.AddRange(StandardScopes.All.ToList());
        return models;
    }
}
```

Once I did that, when I went back to my configuration page, all the scopes were listed and I could finally get my user info.